# How to find the co-ordinate of object which is in between of CAKeyframeAnimation?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

Currently i am moving a png image using CAKeyframeAnimation along a path for 30 seconds. Is there any way to find the co-ordinate of imageview in between the animation? (lets say on 15th second of animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check presentationLayer in your imageview's layer - it contains all informations about layer's current state during animation. e.g. you can get current image center coordinates the following way:

```
CALayer *presLayer = [imageView.layer presentationLayer];
CGPoint currentCenter = presLayer.center;
```

Comment: Initially this worked.. but now presLayer.frame gives negative co-ordinate